# how to set background image in GLWallpaperService Renderer with other object render on it

Tags: android, opengl-es, background, render, glsurfaceview

i want to set background as an image in GLSurfaceView.Renderer replace with black color, is it possible with other object render on it like multiple cube render on it?

[image: screen shot of my issue]

my code of renderer class is given bellow,

```
public MyGLRenderer(Context context){
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config){
gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0,255f); 
gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);          
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);  
gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); 
gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);   
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
gl.glOrthof(0, 1, 0 , 1, -1, 1);

cube.loadTexture(gl);             

gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
gl.glAlphaFunc(GL10.GL_GREATER,0);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);  

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
if (height == 0) { 
    height = 1; 
}

gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); 
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity(); 

GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f,100.0f);

gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity(); 

}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

gl.glLoadIdentity();                 

gl.glPushMatrix();
cube.draw(gl);
gl.glPopMatrix();

}
}
```

Comment: Short questions like this will get closed quickly without an answer if you don't add more detail to it. Try explaining what you tried so far and why it didn't work. Post what ever relevant code you have that shows how to reproduce your problem or where you're stuck and need help.